# error: expected identifier before string constant or error: 'perf' is not a type

Tags: c++, gcc

I am getting below error, I tried this 2 ways but didn't solve it.

Below is the code

```
   class Stat_S{
    public:
        Stat_S(const char *name) :
        {
            ........
        }

        ~Stat_S();
    };


    struct temp {
         Stat_S sp("ppin");
    }
```

error: expected identifier before string constant

```
class Stat_S{
public:
    Stat_S(const char *name) :
    {
        ........
    }

    ~Stat_S();
};

const char *temp="ppin";
struct temp {
     Stat_S sp(temp);
}
```

error: 'temp' is not a type

```
 class Stat_S{
    public:
        Stat_S(const char *name) :
        {
            ........
        }

        ~Stat_S();
    };

    struct temp {
         Stat_S*sp = new Stat_S("ppin");
    }
```

work's fine no error

```
main()
{
 static temp2 *temp;
 temp2 = new temp[2];
}
```

How to solve 1st or 2nd case ?  I want to call the constructor of Stat_S from struct temp. I don't wont to use 3rd case, because I already have big definition that uses dot (.) for sp I don't want to change it to -> after using instance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Inside `struct temp` you're not supposed to write executable code, but members. Code goes into functions, not structs. If you want to have a member which is immediately initialized, then you need `=` or `{}` syntax. Your syntax only works for local variables (that is, within a function)

Comment: why negative points. can you explain so i will be more cautious next time.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess it is because you didn't explain what you want to do.

Comment: please remove it. I am already on border line of down votes to post on any new question :(

Comment: Then edit the question and explain what you want to do, and hope that someone will upvote it ;) And as I already said: it wasn't me who downvoted. Also, the downvote doesn't harm your reputation much, only -2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In-class initialization of non-static members can be performed using brace or equal initializers. The 3rd case is an instance of using equal. To do the 1st or 2nd correctly, use braces like this :

```
struct temp {
         Stat_S sp{"ppin"};
    }
```